# Found syntax error near ')' SQL server

Tags: sql-server

When I run this query don't know why this show error

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

Thank you for help

```
Select 
    Sum(DateDiff(s, Toc1.OutTime, (Select Top 1 Intime 
                                   From tblTokenLogs 
                                   Where TokenId = Toc1.TokenId 
                                     And LogId != Toc1.LogId 
                                     And LogId > Toc1.LogId))) as Sec 
From 
    tblTokenLogs As Toc1 
Where 
    Toc1.TokenId = 1 
    And Toc1.OutTime != '') as SecTotal
```

Comment: Typo -- these are always easier to spot if you format your code...

Comment: You have an extra, unneeded `) as SecTotal` after the last line of your `WHERE` clause - just remove that ...

Comment: remove ) from LINE `And Toc1.OutTime != '') as SecTotal`

Answer (score 0):

Compare this query with your query you will get idea what was wrong!

```
SELECT SUM(
           DATEDIFF(
               s,
               Toc1.OutTime,
               (
                   SELECT TOP 1 Intime
                   FROM   tblTokenLogs
                   WHERE  TokenId = Toc1.TokenId
                          AND LogId != Toc1.LogId
                          AND LogId > Toc1.LogId
               )
           )
       )             AS Sec
FROM   tblTokenLogs  AS Toc1
WHERE  Toc1.TokenId = 1
       AND Toc1.OutTime != ''
```

*Unwanted Alias `) as SecTotal`*

Comment: now shows this type of error "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."@pedram

Comment: Use `GROUP BY Sec` at the end.

Comment: may be can't group by on sec its show invalid column

Comment: you should provide table details along with data and your basic requirement.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Select 
    Sum(DateDiff(s, Toc1.OutTime, Toc2.Intime )) as Sec 
From 
    tblTokenLogs As Toc1
OUTER APPLY (   Select Top 1 Intime 
                From tblTokenLogs 
                Where TokenId = Toc1.TokenId 
                    And LogId != Toc1.LogId 
                    And LogId > Toc1.LogId
                ) AS Toc2
Where 
    Toc1.TokenId = 1 
    And Toc1.OutTime != ''
```